# Opening Safari URL in my app

Tags: objective-c, url, mobile-safari

Is it possible, using Objective-C, to register an action for Safari URLs similar to the "Open In..." dialogue that allows users to open the page in my app? Something like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by either:

- [Registering an URL scheme](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/Inter-AppCommunication/Inter-AppCommunication.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH6-SW11) for your application
- [Registering the file types](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/DocumentInteraction_TopicsForIOS/Articles/RegisteringtheFileTypesYourAppSupports.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010411-SW1) your application supports

Both methods are quite straight forward and only require you to add some info to your applications property lists and some handler methods.

Comment: But would I be able to bring up the "Open In..." dialogue even for web pages?

Comment: No, seeing "Open in..." directly on the page will only work with files that Safari is able to display natively in the browser, but other programs also have registered as able to open. You can't do this for generic web pages. To achieve a similar effect, you could have your app register an URL scheme, and then create a link on the webpage with protocol specifier matching your apps URL scheme. You need control over the webpage for that though, so if you want to be able to send arbitrary pages to your app, this method is no good.